# String separator for a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is my extracted String :

```
extractedString = "1) No structured exercise.\n\n2) Above ideal body Mass index.\n\n3) Cancer gene testing.\n\n4) Suboptimal vitamin D.\n\n5) Slight anaemia."
```

What I am looking for is the output that you see for the dataframe:

```
list = [['No structured exercise'],['Above ideal body Mass index'],['Cancer gene testing']
        ,['Suboptimal vitamin D'],['Slight anaemia']]
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
print(df)
```

Ouput:

```
                             0
0       No structured exercise
1  Above ideal body Mass index
2          Cancer gene testing
3         Suboptimal vitamin D
4               Slight anaemia
```

How best can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this regex:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

data = re.findall(r'\d+\)\s*([^\n\.]+)\s{0,2}', extractedString)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['text'])
print(df)

# Output
                          text
0       No structured exercise
1  Above ideal body Mass index
2          Cancer gene testing
3         Suboptimal vitamin D
4               Slight anaemia
```

Only with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = (pd.Series(extractedString)
        .str.split('\n\n')
        .explode(ignore_index=True)
        .str.extract(r'\d+\)\s*(?P<text>[^\.]+)'))
print(df)

# Output
                          text
0       No structured exercise
1  Above ideal body Mass index
2          Cancer gene testing
3         Suboptimal vitamin D
4               Slight anaemia
```

Comment: I was trying to do something like below code where I want 5 rows as a result. Any idea how to achieve that? My data frame has just 1 row until it hits this code. data = re.findall(r'\d+\)\s*([^\n\.]+)\s{0,2}', extractedString)
            df["Significant findings"] = pd.DataFrame(data)

Comment: What do you mean? The solution doesn't work for your real case?

Comment: It works. As a next step there are further operations onto it. Forget it if it is difficult to understand. But yes, your regex code works fine. (y)

Comment: If my string is : extractedString = '1) Body composition\n\n2) Prostate\n\n3) Liver health\n\n4) Vitamin D\n\n5) Eye pressures' , why is there an extra space after using the regex?

Comment: With your new `extractedString`, the output is `['Body composition', 'Prostate', 'Liver health', 'Vitamin D', 'Eye pressures']`. I don't see any extra space?

Comment: You are correct. Can you please help in explaining what does the regex do? Its evaluation?

Comment: `\d+\)` match the numbering like "1)",  "2)", "3)", ... `\s*` consume whitespace between numbering and your text. `([^\n\.]+)` match any characters which is not a line break. `\s{0, 2}` match 0 (end of string), 1 (not relevant here) or 2 (whitespace, especially line break). You can replace it by `\s*` if you prefer.

Comment: I have another scenario where my extractedString =  'Bilateral ear wax\n\nDermatology referral \n\nExcellent body composition\n\nPoor levels of cardiovascular fitness\n\nTarlov cyst'    What regex change need to be there so that it works/covers both the scenarios? Thank you for the explanation, it helps.

Comment: Try: `data = re.findall(r'(?:\d+\))?\s*([^\n\.]+)\s{0,2}', extractedString)`. `\d+\)` become `(?:\d+\))?` that means `(?:pattern)` to ignore capture group and the last `?` allow 0 occurrence of the previous pattern `\d+\)`.

Comment: No, I have three cases and am looking for generic solution. This is not working for the first case. ```extractedString = "1) High level of fitness.\n\n2) Excellent body composition.\n\n3) Stable gallbladder polyp"
#extractedString = '1) Body composition\n\n2) Prostate\n\n3) Liver health\n\n4) Vitamin D\n\n5) Eye pressures'
#extractedString = 'Bilateral ear wax\n\nDermatology referral \n\nExcellent body composition\n\nPoor levels of cardiovascular fitness\n\nTarlov cyst'```

Comment: Try with `data = [re.search(r'(?:\d+\))?\s*([^\.]+)', text).group(1) for text in re.split('\n\n', extractedString)]`

Comment: Worked this time. May I ask how have you mastered it?

Comment: After all, it was easier to split your data into a list and then attempt to extract the useful part.

Comment: Commendable ...

Answer (score 0):

**This is pretty straightforward you could use pandas like this:**

```
import pandas as pd

extractedString = "1) No structured exercise.\n\n2) Above ideal body Mass index.\n\n3) Cancer gene testing.\n\n4) Suboptimal vitamin D.\n\n5) Slight anaemia."


listOfStrings = extractedString.split("\n\n")


df = pd.DataFrame(listOfStrings)

df = df.apply(lambda x: x[1:-1])
```

first split the string into a list of strings
then we create a DataFrame from the list of strings
lastly remove the leading and trailing characters from each string

I hope this helps!

Comment: Does not fully yield the same output that I am looking for.